# How to rbind data from differing lengths of tables

Tags: r, data-binding, dataframe

Ok, I am sure there is a simple solution to this. Assuming the following data

```
A <- 1:10
B <- rep("Part A", 10)
C <- 10:19
df1 <- data.frame(A,B,C)

A <- 1:9
B <- rep("Part B", 9)
D <- 20:28
df2 <- data.frame(A,B,D)
```

Now I want to create `df3` which the user specifies which column names.
So `df3` should be a 2*19 data frame of only `A` and `B`

This does not work

```
df3 <- rbind(df1[A,B], df2[A,B])
```

I dont want to use `common_cols` or `[,x]` function as my real dataset has over 1000 variables, that are not always in the same order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax isn't quite right for subsetting. Try

```
cols <- c("A", "B")
rbind(df1[,cols], df2[,cols])
```

The columns you want to keep should be a vector of names (or indices/logicals) after the `,`.

Comment: Could also be a vector of logicals, just to add an option

Comment: @docendodiscimus I knew I was going to miss something when I started writing that :)  The subsetting functions do so much.